# $\Theta$-notation of a logarithm

Tags: asymptotics, logarithms

Given $H(x) = lg(f(n))$, where $f(n)$ is an asymptotically positive function,
 is it always true that if $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$, then

$H(x) = lg(\Theta(g(n)))$

$\Rightarrow H(x) = \Theta(lg(g(n)))$

To illustrate,
Is $lg(n + c) = \Theta(lg(n))$ provided that $c > 0$ and $c$ is a big number?

Comment: It is not always true that if $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ then $\log f(n) = \Theta(\log g(n))$.  For example, take $f(n) = 2$ and $g(n) = 1 + 1/n$.  Then $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ but $\log f(n) \neq O(\log g(n)) = O(1/n)$.  

As for your example, $\log(n+c) = \log n + O(1/n)$, so that $\log(n+c) \sim \log n$.

Comment: Please use `\log` or `\ln`.

Answer (score 1):

What is true is that if $f(n) = \Theta(g(n))$ with $f, g > 0$ then $\log f(n) = \log g(n) + O(1)$.  If in addition either $g(n) \to \infty$ or $g(n) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, then
$\log f(n) = \Theta(\log g(n))$.